# iPad third-party calendar component

Tags: calendar, ipad

I need a calendar-App-like UI component in my App. I mean, not necessarily nice and complex like the calendar App, but close enough.

Is there something similar and possibly open source?
Frameworks, API, libraries, snippets and so on?

(I say **iPad** on purpose, not iPhone! I know there are good solutions for iPhone, already)

Comment: You could use the iPhone one, and just tweak the view dimensions a bit to get it working well for the iPad. That's unless you want a completely different look-and-feel from the iPhone calendar implementations..

Comment: paste a code sample, and get the answer prize! :)

Comment: Have you looked into this: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-calendar

Comment: yeah tilo, thank you. but that's for iphone

Answer (score 1):

I know this one
https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar

But I'm not sure if you can customise everything you need.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are looking for but Apple has some good documentation on [Event Kit UI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) frameworks. This would allow you to navigate and use basic calendar functions.